# Insert into a table with sequence of numbers appended to a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am using postgres Sql and I intend to insert a million records into the table. However for one of the columns I want to insert a value which has a number appended to it and increases in sequence. for example:

[image: Sample data]

In the above example, the pxinsname and key have incrementing values appended with a constant text (S-, ABC )

I am unsure how I can incrementally increase the values in the those columns. Trying to use below query -

```
insert into testable (
    pxcommitdatetime,pxsavedatetime,pxcreatedatetime,pxcreateoperator,pxcreateopname,pxinsname,key,tripname, source, destination, passengername,passengerage
)
select
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
test,
test,
// S- "Incremental value",
// ABC S "Incremental value",
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    left(md5(random()::text), 4)
from generate_series(1, 10) s(i)
```

Comment: Why not simply use `s.i` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such purposes you can use sequences:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html

First you will need to create it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE key_seq START 1;
```

And then use in your query as follows:

```
insert into testable (
    pxcommitdatetime,pxsavedatetime,pxcreatedatetime,pxcreateoperator,pxcreateopname,pxinsname,key,tripname, source, destination, passengername,passengerage
)
select
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
test,
test,
// S- "Incremental value",
 "ABC S" || nextval('key_seq')::text,
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text),
    left(md5(random()::text), 4)
from generate_series(1, 10) s(i)
```

Comment: Ok. But this is going to generate the next value everytime I try to use the sequence number in the same query. Can i store the next value in a variable and use that variable in my columns? How can i store the value in a variable in the query?

Comment: Sequence also provides currval function, so you can use nextval() in a first place, and currval() in a second

Comment: Why don't you use `s.i`?